# C# reading LuaTable with LuaInterface that contains Russian letters

Tags: c#, luainterface

so I've been using the LuaInterface library for my C# application to read a LuaTable, one problem I caught upon is that the LuaInterface library doesn't translate russian very well, when I try to output the string into the console, the russian letters just get replaced by questionmarks (?), is there any library that supports unicode-characters, or is there any way I can change it to make it work?

```
        Lua lua = new Lua();
        lua.DoString(File.ReadAllText(@"\luatable.lua"));
        string server = "Ясеневый лес";
        Console.WriteLine(lua["MYTABLE." + server]);
```

Thank you!

Comment: did you try utf8?   string allText = File.ReadAllText(@"\luatable.lua", Encoding.UTF8);

Comment: @CharlesP just tried it, doesn't work sadly.